# how to receive the double array with a function call from JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, primitive

I have a Java method which takes a String as parameter and returns a double array. I am calling it using CallObjectMethod from native code. How do I receive that double array that the Java method is returning and how do I convert it to a normal(C/C++) double array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNI has a `jdoubleArray` type that's returned when you call this method. So something like this:

```
jdoubleArray retVal;

retVal = env->CallObjectMethod(...);
jdouble *element = env->GetIntArrayElements(retVal, 0);
```

And then you can directly use the members of `element`

Comment: may i know what will be the default value of retVal in the above declaration?as well as the default value of element?thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be garbage unless you initialize it to something.

Comment: thanks for the response.how do i know whether the variable retVal has already been used(initialized with some value) or not?

Comment: It will either have a value or be NULL since it's assigned to the result of the CallObjectMethod() function.